# Systematically change the position of an iframe - React

Tags: reactjs

I would like to understand how to dynamically change the position of a component (iframe) for each change of state. I have three different iframes, which I want to render at three different times, and in three different positions. I can't understand if it is possible to enter the coordinates of the positions I want in the state, or there is another way to do this. 
I insert the part of the code concerned, for an easier understanding.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Pubblicita extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    iframeSrcs: ["/300x250", "/160x600", "/468x60"],
    heightSrcs: [250, 600, 60],
    widthSrcs: [300, 160, 468],
    visibility: false
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button style={{ opacity: "0" }} onClick={this.reload}>
          pubblicità
        </button>
        {this.state.visibility ? (
          <iframe
            key={this.state.index}
            title="AdSlot"
            src={this.state.iframeSrcs[this.state.index]}
            height={this.state.heightSrcs[this.state.index]}
            width={this.state.widthSrcs[this.state.index]}
            scrolling="no"
            frameborder="0"
            allowFullScreen="true"
          />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Pubblicita;
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: create a style for the iframe, use absolute positing, top and left values from state, jus like you are trying to do with the height and width.

Comment: I had tried, but it didn't work. I have improved the syntax and it now works. Thank you